# Deadlock in model.predict_generator() with use_multiprocessing=True

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing, deadlock

A strange problem found in `model.predict_generator` when setting `use_multiprocessing=True` and `workers > 1`.
It would stuck (looks like a deadlock?), until I kill it with `Ctrl+C`.
And it raises:

```sh
File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py376tf114cpu/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1060, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception ignored in: <Finalize object, dead>
```

The strangest thing is,
when the `workers` is set to `1`, `2` and `5`, it does not stuck, but it stucks when workers=`3`, `4`, `6`, `7`.
Can't find any patterns here.

Here are my codes.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import *
import numpy as np 
import time 

BATCH_SIZE = 1024
DATA_DIM = 256

def dataloader():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        yield np.random.random((BATCH_SIZE, DATA_DIM)) 

def build_model():
    x = Input((256,), dtype=float)
    e1 = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(x)
    e2 = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(e1)
    e3 = Dense(units=32, activation='relu')(e2)
    e4 = Dense(units=16, activation='relu')(e3)
    e5 = Dense(units=8, activation='relu')(e4)
    e6 = Dense(units=4, activation='relu')(e5)
    y = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(e6)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
    model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_crossentropy'])

    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":

    model = build_model()
    generator = dataloader()

    start = time.time()
    model.predict_generator(generator, 100, verbose=1, max_queue_size=10, workers=5, use_multiprocessing=True)
    finish = time.time()

    print(finish - start)

    """Stuck here when workers is set to 3,4,6,7"""
    """The main thread ends normally, when workers is set to 1,2,5"""
```

And my environments are:

```sh
centos7
tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
keras==2.2.4
```

Any helps?

Comment: you are using a fairly old version of tensorflow. are you able to use a newer version, like 2.x?

Comment: Upgrade to the recent Tensorflow version, In the recent version it gives warning when you use use_multiprocessing=True and workers > 1 to address the same issue which you are facing.